# How do I apply a function to an array and form two separate arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, each

I'm using Ruby 2.4. I have an array with string data elements, that look like

```
["a word1 word2", "b eff", "a idaho orange", "new old shoe", "b mars", ...]
```

I want to form two arrays from the above, applying a function (`.split(/^(a|b)[[:space]]*/i`) to each element of the array.  However, I can't figure out how to form two separate arrays. The following

```
arr.map{ |x| x.split(/^(a|b)[[:space]]*/i) }
```

only results in a single array and has a blank element in front of each element.  Ideally, I'd like the output to be two arrays like

```
["a", "b", "a", "", "b", ...]
["word1 word2", "eff", "idaho orange", "new old shoe", "mars", ...]
```

Comment: Suppose `"new old shoe"` were `"an old shoe"` or `"bold old shoe"`? What would you expect the return value to be (considering that the regex would split on the first character of those two strings)? Did you mean `[[:space:]]+` rather than `[[:space:]]*`?

Comment: When you give an example, 1) make all input values valid Ruby objects (no `"..."`, among other things); 2) assign a variable to all input objects (e.g., `arr = ["a word1 word2", "b eff", "a idaho orange", "new old shoe", "b mars"]`) so that readers can cut and paste to test code and refer to those variables (`arr`) in answers in comments without having to define them; and 3) show your desired output as a valid Ruby object (no variables needed there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
arr.map { |x| a, b, c = x.partition(/^[ab]\s+/); [b.strip, a + c] }.transpose
```

How does this work?

- `partition` splits a string into before-match, match and post-match
- `b.strip` is the match without trailing whitespace
- `a + c` is either the full string (if there was no match the full string is in before-match) or the post-match
- `[..., ...]` creates a tuple, hence creating an array of tuple
- `transpose` switches the rows and columns of a 2D array

Answer (score 2):

## Regex only

This is the shortest I could find :

```
a1, a2 = arr.map{ |x| x.match(/((?:^[ab](?= ))?) *(.*)/).captures}.transpose
```

This example now works with `"activity"` or `"ball"`. It checks if a space follows directly after `a` or `b` at the beginning of the string.

## Split and logic

Another variant would be :

```
a1, a2 = arr.map do |x|
  parts = x.split(/(?<=^a|^b) +/)
  parts.unshift('') if parts.size == 1
  parts
end.transpose
```

Comment: Sweet! Maybe even use `arr.map{ |x| x.match(/^([ab]?) ?(.*)/).captures}.transpose` to better communicate intent.

Comment: Undeleting mine then :)